# psycopg2.copy_expert - insert only new data

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, postgresql-9.1

I am using psycopg2.copy_expert to copy data from CSV to PostgreSQL DB. I run this every day and I want only the new data to be inserted. If data is already present then no action must be perfomed. Is there a way to leverage copy_expert function to do this out of the box or do I have code his logic myself and create a new CSV file that contains only the delta changes?

```
copy_sql = """
           COPY %s FROM stdin WITH CSV HEADER
           DELIMITER as ','
           """
f = open(f"{file_path}", 'r', encoding="utf-8")
cur.copy_expert(sql=copy_sql % table_name, file=f)
```

Comment: copy doesn't deal with delta, it is just a straight up append. sounds like you want `upsert` which you will have to code yourself. seems like a good learning opportunity =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `temporary table` coupled with `ON CONFLICT` to achieve this:

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE buffer (
    field1,
    field2,
    ...
    fieldn
);

COPY buffer FROM STDIN With CSV HEADER DELIMITER as ',';

INSERT INTO table(field1, field2, ... fieldn)
SELECT field1, field2, ... fieldn FROM buffer
ON CONFLICT (ID) DO NOTHING;

DROP TABLE buffer;
```

You should be able to use the `query` above together with a file handle for `copy_expert`.

Comment: Hi, instead of using "ON CONFLICT (ID) DO NOTHING;" how do we instead check if a value of a column has changed and if it hasn't do nothing? thanks

Comment: I don't know if this can be achieved using only `ON CONFLICT`; maybe you could use `ON CONFLICT(id) DO UPDATE` and define a trigger for `before_update` which checks if the values changed.